# how can read environment variable with sql statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, environment-variables

I use Oracle 11g on my systems, and I need to get system's environment variables using SQL.

is there any way to get it?
(for example USER, HOME, PATH, in fact, I need to get my custom environment varibles for system management.)

or I read about dbms_system.get_env() in PL/SQL. How can I using this from my SQL? (sorry, I'm closer to system administrator.)

EDIT:
what I want to do is something like below:

```
=============================
  java: query to get XXX_INFO
  ---------------------------
server:
=============================
              |
=============================
  dbms: select SOMETHING...
  ---------------------------
server: export XXX_INFO=myXXX
=============================
```

Comment: To use `dbms_system` through plain SQL, you could create a wrapper function that returns the value you ask for. You're looking for the environment for the current session though, hopefully, not the environment for the session that started the instance.

Comment: @AlexPoole, as a system administrator and system oriented developer, I want to get information about the environtment of the database instance. My goal is to draw system map automatically by set (on server) and get (from was/dbms via java) some environment informations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sys_context function to get information that you need.
E.g - to get ip address of the system use it as

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') from dual
```

output

```
| SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') |
|-------------------------------------|
|                          10.0.0.113 |
```

Follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117) for more information

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117

Comment: Thanks Alex, modifying the post.

Comment: I want to get more information about server environment. In fact, I need to set my own environment variables for my purpose and get it through DBMS. I already check variables on USERENV namespace, but It has only SERVER_HOST for me.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: this is IP of the client; IP of the server is here: `UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS`

Answer (score 2):

Install DBMS_SYSTEM as SYSDBA, from SQL*Plus.  Then create a function and grant execute on it to your user.  Normally creating objects in SYS is a bad idea, but since since DBMS_SYSTEM is undocumented you probably want to avoid granting the whole package to anyone.

```
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/dbmsutil.sql

Session altered.

Package created.

Synonym created.

Grant succeeded.

Session altered.

SQL> create or replace function sys.get_env(p_var in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  2     v_return_value varchar2(4000);
  3  begin
  4     dbms_system.get_env(p_var, v_return_value);
  5     return v_return_value;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> grant execute on sys.get_env to <your user>;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Now from your user:

```
SQL> select sys.get_env('ORACLE_HOME') from dual;

SYS.GET_ENV('ORACLE_HOME')
--------------------------------------------------
C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle 12c, you can use a procedure in SQL like this:

```
WITH
  FUNCTION get_env(p_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_ret VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    dbms_system.get_env(p_name, v_ret);
    RETURN v_ret;
  END;
SELECT get_env('HOME') FROM dual
```

Of course you will also need access to `dbms_system` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I can do this (on Exadata)

```
select *
from V$instance;
```

And this gets me:

STATUS, PARALLEL, ARCHIVER, LOG_SWITCH_WAIT, LOGINS, SHUTDOWN_PENDING, DATABASE_STATUS, INSTANCE_ROLE, ACTIVE_STATE, BLOCKED, CON_ID, INSTANCE_MODE, EDITION, FAMILY, DATABASE_TYPE

Then:

```
select *
from V$database;
```

DBID, **NAME**, CREATED, RESETLOGS_CHANGE#, RESETLOGS_TIME, PRIOR_RESETLOGS_CHANGE#, PRIOR_RESETLOGS_TIME, LOG_MODE, CHECKPOINT_CHANGE#, ARCHIVE_CHANGE#, CONTROLFILE_TYPE, CONTROLFILE_CREATED, CONTROLFILE_SEQUENCE#, CONTROLFILE_CHANGE#, CONTROLFILE_TIME, OPEN_RESETLOGS, VERSION_TIME, OPEN_MODE,PROTECTION_MODE, PROTECTION_LEVEL, REMOTE_ARCHIVE,ACTIVATION#, SWITCHOVER#, DATABASE_ROLE, ARCHIVELOG_CHANGE#, ARCHIVELOG_COMPRESSION, SWITCHOVER_STATUS, DATAGUARD_BROKER, GUARD_STATUS, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_MIN, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_PK, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_UI, FORCE_LOGGING, PLATFORM_ID, PLATFORM_NAME, RECOVERY_TARGET_INCARNATION#, LAST_OPEN_INCARNATION#, CURRENT_SCN, FLASHBACK_ON, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_FK, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_ALL, DB_UNIQUE_NAME, STANDBY_BECAME_PRIMARY_SCN, FS_FAILOVER_MODE, FS_FAILOVER_STATUS, FS_FAILOVER_CURRENT_TARGET, FS_FAILOVER_THRESHOLD, FS_FAILOVER_OBSERVER_PRESENT, FS_FAILOVER_OBSERVER_HOST, CONTROLFILE_CONVERTED, PRIMARY_DB_UNIQUE_NAME, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_PL, MIN_REQUIRED_CAPTURE_CHANGE#, CDB, CON_ID, PENDING_ROLE_CHANGE_TASKS, CON_DBID, FORCE_FULL_DB_CACHING, SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_SR

In my case NAME is what I needed